# How to select dynamic column value from a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, select

I have a table called "TableA" which has the following records:

TableA:

```
      ID       Jan       Feb
     ----     -----     -------
      1      '01/12'    '04/12'
```

Here I want to select any one of the column value from the table. But the column name is assigned to a variable. We don't know the exact column name.

For Example:

```
    Declare @Month VARCHAR(20)
    SET @Month = 'Feb'

    Select @Month from TableA
```

It gives the Output as follows:

```
    'Feb'
```

But the Desired Output is '04/12'

How to get the desired output?

Comment: before you go down the path of dynamic SQL (as the answers so far have suggested), make sure you understand how to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: what problem are you trying to solve? how many rows are you expecting to have in the table?  how are you planning on using the table? you could use exwc('select ' + @month + 'from tableA')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Declare @colName VARCHAR(20)
SET @colName = 'Feb'

Exec('select '+ @colName+' from TableA')
```

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
Declare @Month VARCHAR(20)
     SET @Month = QUOTENAME('Feb')
 exec('Select '+@Month+' from TableA')
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `UNPIVOT`

```
select months
from TableA
unpivot 
(months for m in (Jan, Feb)) pvt
where m=@month
```

It's a much safer solution than dynamic SQL as it isn't vulnerable to a SQL Injection attack

Answer (score 2):

Use EXEC or sp_executesql

EXEC:

```
Declare @Month NVARCHAR(20)
SET @Month = 'Feb'
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000)
SET @SQL = 'Select ' + @Month + ' from TableA'
EXEC(@SQL)
```

<s>sp_executesql is preferable, as it parameterizes the variable:</s>

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000)
SET @SQL = 'Select @Month from TableA'
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, 
              N'@Month NVARCHAR(20)',
              @Month = 'Feb'
```

(This just returns the constant 'Feb' - column names can't be variables )

Comment: You need to try your second version of the query.

Comment: Thanks - corrected. I was trying to advocate the use of parameterization to avoid SQL injection.